# How do I find the location of the picture saved on my lock screen?

Tags: display-settings, pictures, system-preferences

I want to save the picture that comes up when i enter my pw but can't find it's location. Any searches that come up are either how to change it or isn't what i am looking for. Also, the main image that i have saved blurs when the box comes up. How do fix these issues? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: They're usually kept in your user profile, in the (hidden) AppData > Local > Packages > Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy > LocalState > Assets folder. Those images don't have an extension. You'll have to copy-paste them in another folder, then batch rename them from command line with "ren *.*  *.jpg" to give them a .jpg (in my example) file extension. EDIT: hard to post the correct syntax in comment so going on answer.

Answer (score 1):

They're usually kept in your user profile, in the (hidden) `%AppData%\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets` folder.

Those images don't have an extension. You'll have to copy-paste them into another folder, then batch rename them from the command line.

Comment: I've edited out the suggested command, as it's dangerous.

Comment: Might I ask why it's "dangerous"? If you copy-paste those extensionless files onto another folder, *then* batch-rename them via Command Line, I don't see the danger. Care to elaborate? FWIW, you can even keep them in the original folder *and* rename them with a .jpg extension without compromising stability or security, but it's best to copy them in a different folder.